# Stop preview after photo is taken

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, photo

My app is supposed to take a photo, then stop there showing the photo, save it in a file and move on to another view.

I use the `Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera` and wait after a photo is taken for `CaptureCompleted` to take the image and for `CaptureImageAvailable` to store it and then move on.

Whan happens is: After a picture is taken, I get the camera preview again, which might be confusing for users (though a progress-bar is shown to tell them "wait pls". still not nice) and after 1-2 seconds it shows the taken picture again and moves on to the next view.

Is there a nice way to disable this preview-thing?
If I dispose the PhotoCamera after the first event, it hangs. If I dispose it after the 2nd event, it doesn't seem to make much difference..

**Edit:**

```
private void Cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    this.imageStream = e.ImageStream;

    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
    {
        this.image = new BitmapImage();
        this.image.SetSource(this.imageStream);
        this.PreviewImage.Source = this.image;

        // Part where I store the image into a file.

        // Part where I navigate to the next view.
    });
}
```

I need that Dispatcher-Thing because setting images and navigating needs the UI-thread but the method runs in a different one.
Also a strange point: it doesn't matter that the PreviewImage lies OVER the canvas with the camera-preview. It is still overwritten as soon as the picture is taken and being processed... ôo

The problem might be that I do many things and the UI is never refreshed. I could add a small sleep (1-5ms) but that would be async again. Also I can't do this completely serparated because the storing part makes a "screenshot" which should contain the final image instead of the camera-preview-thing.

**Edit2:**

I see the main problem in the capture itself. It takes a picture, shows it for a while, then switches to the camera preview and then back to my shown picture.

Comment: can you add the code for this?

Comment: added the code above :)